# CodeIgniter append string to table name

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my codeIgniter project I have separate tables to each user. like, tbl_user1, tbl_user2, tbl_user3, tbl_user4, etc. this 1,2,3,4 are user id numbers.

after particular user logged in to the system, i need to access table which is related to user. (ex. for user 2, need to fetch data from tbl_user2 table).

I have session variable containing user id,

```
$uid=$this->session->userdata('uid');  //$uid=2 for **user 2**
```

how to use this with my model and controller,

ex. controller

`$this->tbl_user('username');   //$this->tbl_user.$uid('username');`  - not working

ex. model

```
 $this->db->select('tbl_user.$uid.*', false);  - //not working
    $this->db->from('tbl_user.$uid'); - //not working
```

please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller**:

```
$this->{'tbl_user' . $uid}('username');
```

**model**: Use double quote

```
$this->db->select("tbl_user.$uid.*", false);
$this->db->from("tbl_user.$uid");
```